# cAdvisor : Could not configure a source for OOM detection

Tags: linux, kubernetes, prometheus, amazon-eks, cadvisor

I have deployed cAdvisor DaemonSet on Kubernetes (EKS) with following manifest

```
---

apiVersion: v1
kind: ServiceAccount
metadata:
  name: cadvisor
  namespace: kube-monitoring

---

kind: ClusterRole
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: cadvisor
rules:
  - apiGroups: ['policy']
    resources: ['podsecuritypolicies']
    verbs:     ['use']
    resourceNames:
    - cadvisor

---

kind: ClusterRoleBinding
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
metadata:
  name: cadvisor
roleRef:
  apiGroup: rbac.authorization.k8s.io
  kind: ClusterRole
  name: cadvisor
subjects:
- kind: ServiceAccount
  name: cadvisor
  namespace: kube-monitoring

---

apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: DaemonSet
metadata:
  name: cadvisor
  namespace: kube-monitoring
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      name: cadvisor
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        name: cadvisor
    spec:
      serviceAccountName: cadvisor
      containers:
      - name: cadvisor
        image: google/cadvisor:latest
        resources:
          requests:
            memory: 400Mi
            cpu: 400m
          limits:
            memory: 2000Mi
            cpu: 800m
        ports:
          - name: http
            containerPort: 8080
            protocol: TCP
        volumeMounts:
        - name: rootfs
          mountPath: /rootfs
          readOnly: true
        - name: var-run
          mountPath: /var/run
          readOnly: true
        - name: sys
          mountPath: /sys
          readOnly: true
        - name: docker
          mountPath: /var/lib/docker
          readOnly: true
        - name: disk
          mountPath: /dev/disk
          readOnly: true
      automountServiceAccountToken: false
      terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
      volumes:
      - name: rootfs
        hostPath:
          path: /
      - name: var-run
        hostPath:
          path: /var/run
      - name: sys
        hostPath:
          path: /sys
      - name: docker
        hostPath:
          path: /var/lib/docker
      - name: disk
        hostPath:
          path: /dev/disk

---
```

But in the cAdvisor container logs I see following messages

```
W0608 16:00:47.238042       1 manager.go:349] Could not configure a source for OOM detection, disabling OOM events: open /dev/kmsg: no such file or directory
```

I can connect to cAdvisor UI at `http://localhost:8080/containers/` without any issue.

What is wrong in this cAdvisor setup ?

Comment: Same problem here. v0.36

Answer (score 0):

I solved the same issue with

```
privileged: true
```